# Fetching data in constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is a good practice to fetch data in javascript class `constructor()`?

E.g. In react class `constructor()`, every tutorial which I find fetch data in `componendDidMount()`, but no one explein why We can't do it in `constructor()`.

Question concerns javascript classes at all, not only `react`.

Comment: `componentDidMount` is better for a number of different reasons. E.g. the constructor will be run in server side rendering, but `componentDidMount` will not.

Answer (score 22):

Constructor is called before the component is mounted (as stated here in #constructor doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

To answer your question, the explanation lies in the lifecycle of a react component and the need to redraw when the state changes. By doing async calls in constructor, you may trigger setState before your component is mounted.

Doing async calls in constructor will mess with the re-render and your component will sometimes not re-render if you call setState in the constructor.

From doc:

> You should not call setState() in the constructor(). Instead, if your component needs to use local state, assign the initial state to this.state directly in the constructor:
>
> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in the constructor. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.

Answer (score 1):

A class constructor is a function which gets called only when function initialises for the first time in DOM.
In trivial language behaviour, only when we instantiate a class using new keyword, its constructor gets called.
Now if we fetch data in Javascript Classes constructor:

1. In case as React if the data fetched is responsible for interacting
       with DOM(UI), it will fail as DOM gets ready only after component
       mounts, assured by componentDidMount.
2. The Data fetching function will also not be called when component re renders as constructor is called only once and hence data wont update for UI(DOM)

Constructors are used generally for default value assignment and declaring class related attributes.

Answer (score -1):

[Javascript introducted classes in ECMAScript2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). 
 They are primarily syntactic sugar for Javascript's prototype-based inheritance. React has a class type of `Component` that comes with lifecycle methods and some other goodies which you can read more about [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

Generally speaking it is best practice to fetch your data in the lifecycle method `componentDidMount`.  Your component needs a place to put the data after it has been retrieved and when this lifecycle method has been called you can be assured that `render()` has been called at least once.