# Cannot read a an object in Component, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I having a problem reading a value of an object in a Component in React. I am trying to read and write the "recordCount" but I am getting the error saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'recordCount' of undefined.

Any idea why it is throwing the error?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class UrunlerComponentList extends Component {
    displayName = UrunlerComponentList.name

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { urunler_: [], recordCount: 0, loading: true };


    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:55992/api/search/arama?q=&PageIndex=1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ urunler_: data.products, recordCount: data.RecordCount, loading: false });
            });
    }

    static renderUrunlerTable(urunler_) {
        return (
            <div>
                <header className="mb-3">
                    <div className="form-inline">
                        <strong className="mr-md-auto"> {recordCount} Items found </strong>
                    </div>
                </header>

                {
                    urunler_.map(urun =>
                        <article className="card card-product-list">
                                                ...............................
                                                ...............................
                                                ...............................
                        </article>
                    )}
            </div>


        );
    }

    render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : UrunlerComponentList.renderUrunlerTable(this.state.urunler_);

        return (
            <div>
                {contents}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Additional suggested answer on top of the answer below, why you may not want to call `fetch` in `constructor`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182526/fetching-data-in-constructor

Comment: the error is thrown at the bottom line, where I use {this.state.recordCount}

Comment: I added the all source code for further investigation

Comment: And which line contains the error now? Given that the implementation of `renderUrunlerTable` changed?

Comment: So is it working now?

Comment: Now, it says "TypeError: UrunlerComponentList.renderUrunlerTable is not a function"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using a static method, this won't refer to the Component and thus, this.state is undefined.

You can make the method as non-static and the method should work. Also, make sure if you are not using arrow functions, you need to bind the method in the constructor function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class UrunlerComponentList extends Component {
    displayName = UrunlerComponentList.name

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { urunler_: [], recordCount: 0, loading: true };
        this.renderUrunlerTable = this.renderUrunlerTable.bind(this);

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:55992/api/search/arama?q=&PageIndex=1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ urunler_: data.products, recordCount: data.RecordCount, loading: false });
            });
    }

    renderUrunlerTable(urunler_) {
        return (
            <div>
                <header className="mb-3">
                    <div className="form-inline">
                        <strong className="mr-md-auto"> {this.state.recordCount} Items found </strong>
                    </div>
                </header>

                {
                    urunler_.map(urun =>
                        <article className="card card-product-list">
                                                ...............................
                                                ...............................
                                                ...............................
                        </article>
                    )}
            </div>


        );
    }

    render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : this.renderUrunlerTable(this.state.urunler_);

        return (
            <div>
                {contents}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Use this code snippet instead of yours.

Comment: I didnt understand what you meant. would you please give a sample?

Comment: You have the method `static renderUrunlerTable(urunler_){`. Remove the word `static`. It should just be `static renderUrunlerTable(urunler_){`.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't realize you are not using arrow functions. In that case, you need to bind the method as did in the updated answer in constructor.

Comment: Binding might not be necessary. It all depends on how `renderUrunlerTable` is actually called. A more complete example is necessary (@ArifYILMAZ).

Answer (score -1):

please move your fetch call in componentDidMount()(recommended)
or
if you want to fetch in constructor use --> this.state = { urunler_: data.products, recordCount: data.RecordCount, loading: false }

Comment: How does this fix the problem that `this.state` is `undefined`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961853/what-will-happen-if-i-use-setstate-function-in-constructor-of-a-class-in-react